# how to apply matrix4x4 to a InstancedBufferGeometry position

Tags: three.js

i tried with the threejs example [webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=insta#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic) given,

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector4();
var m4 = new THREE.Matrix4();
m4 = m4.fromArray(array16);
vector = vector.applyMatrix4(m4);
offsets.setXYZ(i, vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
```

vector set to offset
the offset is also happening,

for orientation

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector4();
var m4 = new THREE.Matrix4();
m4 = m4.fromArray(array16);
var rotMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation(m4);
var vector1 = new THREE.Vector4();
vector1.setAxisAngleFromRotationMatrix(rotMatrix).normalize();
orientations.setXYZW(i, vector1.x, vector1.y, vector1.z, vector1.w);
```

x,y,z,w of vector passed as attribute

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; // optional
uniform mat4 modelMatrix; // optional
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;// optional
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec4 customColor;
attribute vec3 offset;   
attribute vec4 orientation;     
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 worldPosition;
        
void main() {
vec3 vPosition = position;
vColor = customColor;
vec3 vcV = cross(orientation.xyz, vPosition);
vec3 nPosition = vcV * (2.0 * orientation.w ) + (cross(orientation.xyz, vcV) * 2.0 + vPosition);
nPosition += offset.xyz;
worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(nPosition, 1.0);
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( nPosition , 1.0);
}
```

this orientation is the problem area here i have enclosed my shader code for reference

Kindly guide me..
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can anyone please guide me, where i make mistake.

Comment: var rotMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation(m4);
var q= new THREE.Quaternion();
q.setAxisAngleFromRotationMatrix(rotMatrix).normalize();
orientations.setXYZW(i, q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w);  did the magic, now orientation working awesome. mr.doob n Co. developing fantastic things